# REGEX - Capture everything exept the sentence who start with a "["

Tags: regex, bash, macos, google-postmaster

I try since 2 day to write an Regex who capture some information from my postmaster digest.

Exemple:

> 0.32768:0A006832, 4.33024:DD040000 [Stage: CreateMessage]Final-Recipient: rfc822;tXXXXXXXions.croXXXXXy@cXXXXXXXtique.frAction: failedStatus: 5.2.2Diagnostic-Code: smtp;554 5.2.2 mailbox full;

I want to capture sentence like that:

- Final-Recipient:
- Action:
- Status:
- Diagnostic-Code:
- Remote-MTA:

BUT i dont want to capture

- [Stage]:

I wrote a regex who work perfectly fine for capturing :

`([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\-)?[A-Z]{1,3}[a-z]*\:\`

But sadly i dont know how to says to my regex to NOT capturing sentences that start with a "["

i tried this :

`[^\[]([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\-)?[A-Z]{1,3}[a-z]*\:\`

This avoid capturing "[Stage:" but capture one caracters before each other captured sentences.

Anyone know how to capture my postmaster errors ?

Thanks in advance.

(NB: Edited i removed "failedStatus:" and replaced by "Status: ")

Answer (score 0):

Add `(?<!(\[))` before your first regex. the final result would be what you want.

complete answer:
`(?<!(\[))([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\-)?[A-Z]{1,3}[a-z]*\:\`

explanation:
You want to prevent having `[` element before your phrase which in regex would be `(\[)` and you want to don't have it before phrase which means you want to use `not equal lookBehind`. in regex `?<` is lookBehind and `!` is not.
so what you need is `?<!(\[)`

Comment: Thank you very much!

This dont like to work with my SED but may work with some PERL

The command 

`sed -E -e $'s/(?<!\[)([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\-)?[A-Z]{1,3}[a-z]*\:\ /\\\n\\1/g' File.eml`


Return me 


`sed: 1: "s/(?<!A)([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+ ...": RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid`

Comment: CONFIRMED! Work with PERL : `perl -pe 's/(?<!\[)(([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\-)?[A-Z]{1,3}[a-z]*\:\ )/\n\1\2/g'` THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`, you can use capture groups for the first part that matches any character except `]` and another group for the whole last part including the optional capture group inside.

Use those in the replacement with a newline between group 1 and group 2 `\1\n\2`

**Note** that your pattern would not match `failedStatus:` as it does not start with a capital letter.

Also you can omit this quantifier `{1}` as 1 is the default, and you don't have to escape `\-` and  `\:` and `\`

```
sed -E 's/([^\[])(([A-Z][a-z]+-)?[A-Z]{1,3}[a-z]*: )/\1\n\2/g' File.eml
```

Output

```
0.32768:0A006832, 4.33024:DD040000 [Stage: CreateMessage]
Final-Recipient: rfc822;tXXXXXXXions.croXXXXXy@cXXXXXXXtique.fr
Action: failed
Status: 5.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad! I made a mistake in my original question!

I want to capture these fields:

**Final-Recipient:

-Action:

-Status:

-Diagnostic-Code:

Remote-MTA:**

But not this ONE :
**-[Stage: ...**

So the regex from ghazal khaki is correct and works fine!

Again thanks for your support guys!